# Why do I get a 'no authenticationScheme was specified' error when using OAuth2 in an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an application that uses Aurelia as front end and ASP.NET Core for its Web API.

I have to put some Authentication and Authorization around my web API. I am trying to use OAuth (Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth) for this purpose.

I have couple of questions here

1. I would like to know whether if its possible to just use data(users) from a sql server database for authentication. All the examples were tied to entity framework. So had a hard time in decoupling that.

I started with a bare minimum project and just updated my start up class.

This is my configure services method in startup class

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddOAuth("", Options =>
            {
                Options.ClientId = "MyApp";
                Options.ClientSecret = "MyAppSecret";
                Options.CallbackPath = new PathString("//");
                Options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44360/account/authorize";
                Options.TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44360/account/token";
                Options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {

                };
                Options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = async context =>
                {

                };
                Options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context =>
                {

                };
                Options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = async context =>
                {

                };
            });
```

2. I added the default schema but still getting the error. Am i missing something?

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; I [found another example here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/) and fixed my issue by adding additional options to AddAuthentication():

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "";
            }).AddOAuth("", Options => ...);
```